# How do I create a jagged array that produces a random amount arrays inside an array with random values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

```js
var array = [];
var list = "<ul>";
   
for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(Math.random() * 20); i++){
 array[i] = [parseInt(Math.random() * 10)];
 list += "<li>" + array[i];
     
 for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
  array[i][j] += parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
  list += " " + array[i][j];
 }
 list += "</li>"
}
    
list += "</ul>"
    
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML += list;
```

```html
<div id="print">
</div>
```

My goal is to create a jagged array.

I want to initialize an array and create random sets of array inside the initial array that also contains random numbers.

The output I'm looking for is something like this:

- 4 2 5
- 1 10 3 4 5 6
- 7 1 4 8
- 6 9
- 1
- 4 6 7

..but when I run the code I have so far I only receive two columns of random integers every time I run the program. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This code should generate the type of array you are looking for.

```
function createRandomArray(){
    //Create empty Array
    var out=[];
    //random element count for outer array
    var outerLength=parseInt(Math.random()*20)+1;

    //fill outer array with random arrays
    for(var i=0;i<outerLength;i++){
        //inner element count and initialisation
        var innerLength=parseInt(Math.random()*10)+1;
        var inner=[];
        for(var j=0;j<innerLength;j++){
            //fill the inner array with random numbers
            inner.push(parseInt(Math.random()*10)+1);
        }
        //add the inner array to the outer array
        out.push(inner);
    }
    return out;
}
```

**Edit**

I will try to explain why your code does not work

`for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(Math.random() * 20); i++){`

In every loop iteration the `Math.random` part is executed again. You should save it in an extra variable.

`array[i] = [parseInt(Math.random() * 10)];`

You initialize the sub-array with one random number

`for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){`

And iterate over this sub array(which has only one element). So this loop is only called once per sub-array. Because of this every Array has exactly 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
  array[i] = [parseInt(Math.random() * 10)];
```

*array[0]* is assigned an array of length 1 and containing a single digit integer, assume it's 5 so that *array* looks like `[[5]]`. Then later:

```
for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
```

Note here *array[i].length* is 1.

```
    array[i][j] += parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
```

So this adds a number to the value at *array[0][0]*, which was 5 and now might be say 8, so you have an array like:

```
[[8]]
```

Since the length of *array* is still only 1, and *j* is incremented to 1 also, the loop ends.

Note that if you use:

```
array[i][j].push(parseInt(Math.random() * 10));
```

you'll have an infinite loop since you will increment the length of the array at the same rate you increment j and it will always be j + 1. You need to set *j* to a static value, e.g.

```
for (var j=0, jLimt = parseInt(Math.random()*10); j<jLimt; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into trouble because your recalculating a random value every iteration of the for loop.

It's even easier. One thing I noticed is your code is doing too much. It's creating random arrays, creating a random array of random arrays, creating HTML, string concatenating the HTML, and mutating the DOM. That's a lot for one conceptual function to do. How about breaking up the logic into single responsibility functions and compose them together:

```js
function randomValue(offset) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (offset || 10));
}

function randomArray(size, valueFn) {
  var i, arr = [];
  size = randomValue(size || 20) + 1;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr.push(valueFn());
  }
  return arr;
}

function randomJaggedArray(size, offset) {
  return randomArray(size, function() {
    return randomArray(size, function() {
      return randomValue(offset);
    });
  });
}

function toHTML(arr) {
  var html = '<ul>';
  html += arr.map(function(value) {
    var li = '<li>';
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      li += '' + value;
    } else {
      li += value.join(' ');
    }
    li += '</li>';
    return li;
  }).join('');
  html += '</ul>';
  return html;
}

document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = toHTML(randomJaggedArray(20, 10));
```

```html
<div id="print"></div>
```